# running into an issue at work accessing an index on a table

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests

I'm having trouble trying to figure out why accessing row 0, col 3 on an HTML table isn't working. I'm using C# and Visual Studio.

While debugging if we let it pass by once and then set it back to the same line that grabs it as a variable then it would work. But never the first time through, if I went for row 1, col 3, being the next cell down one, it would grab it fine and so on with any others except for row 1 (being index 0).

Segments of the code are as follows, but we couldn't figure out why it wasn't working on specifically the first row, we even tried adding a delay to make sure the page was fully loaded and still wasn't returning any value. To remind you, it worked on every row but the first, even when the item in the first row was changed. The item in the first row, fourth col will always be changing so there is no specific class or identifier I can just access it by every time.

Any clue why it's not working for the first row and any fixes would be greatly appreciated. I have a work around, but it would just be easier to do it like this:

```
    using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.HtmlControls;

    var browser = BrowserWindow.Launch("https://blah.com/");

    var cell = GetCell(browser, 2, 3);

    Console.WriteLine(cell.Value.ToString());

    HtmlCell GetCell(UITestControl parent, int row, int column)
            {
                var cell = new HtmlCell(parent);
                cell.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlCell.PropertyNames.RowIndex, row.ToString());
                cell.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlCell.PropertyNames.ColumnIndex, column.ToString());

                return cell;
            }
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of the html? It might help figure out what's happening.

Comment: Could you put a breakpoint after the line `var cell = GetCell(browser, 0, 3);` (assuming you try to get row 0 column 3), and see what value is returned, is it null or does it throw an exception? Also I am not sure if the rows are 0 starting or 1.

Comment: as i work for Intel and that kind of information is confidential i cannot @fallenidol. rows do start at 0, when i indexed as 1 it gave me the text in the second row. it returned null. it will run through the whole thing but the output will be blank, however it works perfectly well when accessing 1, 3 or any other row

Comment: i will see what i can do tomorrow to provide more information on the html in a general form. ill post tomorrow between 2 and 6 PST

Comment: Please read [mcve]. Many people find that creating an [mcve] helps them to solve the problem themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Allen,

You may want to make sure that the header row of your table is of the same form as the remaining rows.

You are correct that row indexes start at 0.

You may want to try creating a debugging method. Remember that a cell is a child of a row. Pass in a table as a ui parent object and iterate through each row, then iterate through each cell and see what the debugger is showing you as values for these objects (including their types).

My suspicion is it'll be something to do with the header structure or that a  element has a different object type than  rather than HtmlCell